# Should i pass CameraDescription between screens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a doubt about [Flutter](https://flutter.dev).
I have the code below

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

  final CameraDescription firstCamera = cameras.first;

    runApp(MyApp(
      homeScreen: HomeScreen(
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ));
}
```

Inside `HomeScreen` screen i have a menu, one of the menu options can redirect to the `CameraScreen` class, which uses the camera.

So, my doubt is, should i get the available cameras in `main()` method and passing the camera as parameter to `HomeScreen` and after to `CameraScreen`, or is better to do this inside the `CameraScreen` class?

If the answer is the second option, how can i do this?